# Which Angular DataGrid library to use?

Tags: library, angular

I am looking for a DataGrid library to use on a new Angular project. The main functionalities I want are:

- Server side filtering.
- Pagination (first, previous, next, last) (Page [1] of 10) (Results Per Page: [5])
- Sortable columns.
- Check/Select rows.

On the previous project we used jQuery and EasyUI for the DataGrid and were more or less satisfied. Now we want to move to an Angular solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

7.5 yeras later, with no answer. Too late for OP, but might help others. I don't know of anything better than AgGrid, especially if - as OP does - you need [server side filtering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/server-side-model/).

I have never needed more than the free community edition. Popular? It has > 600k monthly downloads!

It supports JS, Angular, react & Vue. There is a demo [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php).

Plus it also supports charting and has incredibly good docuemntation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Syncfusion Angular DataGrid Component

https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-components/angular-grid

Online Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/bootstrap5/grid/over-view

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion